# Pin does not appear on the map (CommunityToolkit Maps) run from Windows

Tags: c#, maui, maui-community-toolkit

I am working with net 8 I have the following code:

```
mapa.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Location(41.21301, 1.73250), Distance.FromMiles(0.5)));
        string cadenaSituacion = "41º 12.8 N'  001º 43.9' E";
        var pin = new Pin
        {
            Label = cadenaSituacion,
            Address = cadenaSituacion,
            Type = PinType.Place,
            Location = new Location(41.21301, 1.73250)
        };
        mapa.Pins.Add(pin);
```

Running the app on Mac the pin is displayed correctly, but on Windows it is not,for it to be displayed in Windows I have to change:

```
string cadenaSituacion = "41º 12.8' N  001º 43.9' E"
```

for :

```
string cadenaSituacion = "41º 12.8 N  001º 43.9 E"
```

I have to remove the single quote. Any idea how to fix it.
Thank you

Comment: Is there any log about this problem?

Comment: No, It doesn't give any error, it just doesn't show the pin

Comment: You can create a new issue [here](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/dotnet/issues).

Comment: Have you tried using [Conditional compilation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/invoke-platform-code?view=net-maui-8.0#conditional-compilation)?